# django-registration vs scratch registration implementation for admin-activated accounts

Tags: django, django-registration, user-registration

I need to implement a fairly simple registration workflow:

- User fills a registration request (form).
- Admin(s) recieves a notification about the registration request. (maybe)
- Admin(s) activates desired users from the django-admin interface.
- User recieves a notification about the activation of his account.

I've been reading about the [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.1/) application.

From what I've read, it seems that this app is used very frequently but I'm not sure of its advantages.

So, my question is: from the following options (I'm open to other alternatives as well), what would be better in this case?

- Implement all the registration from scratch.
- Extend one of the backends on django-registration.
- Write a django-registration backend from scratch.

Also, **reasons** supporting the choice please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to take a look at [django inspectional registration](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-inspectional-registration) it fits your use case perfectly. It's an enhanced version of django registration since the latter doesn't have the function to approve/deny user's registration.

Comment: It seems appropiate thx. I'm a bit worried about the version being 0.2x. Have you tested it on production?

Comment: I tried the package yesterday on the latest version of django and managed to hack it around to cater to my use case. Currently, django inspectional registration is (user register --> admin approve --> user received verification url and enters password --> user account fully created). I find it weird that the user only verify url after the admin approve so i tweaked it to (user register --> user received verification url and enters password --> admin approve --> user account fully created).

Comment: @stupidbodo: I know this is an old post, but in case you still read this, could you give me some hint or any advice how did you tweak the registration. I need the same case like yours.